# How to use scrollTop as percentage rather than pixels

Tags: javascript, scrolltop

I am animating divs to shrink when they start to get to the top of a page. Unfortunately, scrollTop is a pixel number which is not responsive-friendly since the pixel amounts will be different for every device.

My solution is to use percentage of the window but I'm still learning and I'm not sure how to do it. This is where I'm at so far-

https://codepen.io/muskaurochs/pen/NWNMOYG

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 200 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 200) {
    document.getElementById("header").style.width = "80%";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("header").style.width = "100%";
  }
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 350 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 350) {
    document.getElementById("header2").style.width = "80%";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("header2").style.width = "100%";
  }
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 600 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 600) {
    document.getElementById("header3").style.width = "80%";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("header3").style.width = "100%";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do some sort of calculations to get the percentages but you don't need to do that. You should get the top of the div using `offsetTop` instead of adding in a fixed value, e.g.

```
if (document.body.scrollTop > document.getElementById("header").offsetTop || 
    document.documentElement.scrollTop > document.getElementById("header").offsetTop) {
```

The code you have for each header div is nearly the same so you could remove the repetition if you keep all the div elements in an array, and loop though that to get the `offsetTop` and set the style, like this:

```
function scrollFunction() {

  for (var i = 0; i < headerdivs.length; i++) {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > headerdivs[i].offsetTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop > headerdivs[i].offsetTop) {
      headerdivs[i].style.width = "80%";
    } else {
      headerdivs[i].style.width = "100%";
    }
  }
}
```

I used the code from your codepen here to show you how to make it work.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

headerdivs = [
  document.getElementById("header"),
  document.getElementById("header2"),
  document.getElementById("header3"),
]

function scrollFunction() {

  for (var i = 0; i < headerdivs.length; i++) {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > headerdivs[i].offsetTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop > headerdivs[i].offsetTop) {
      headerdivs[i].style.width = "80%";
    } else {
      headerdivs[i].style.width = "100%";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
  display: block;
}

#header2 {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
  display: block;
}

#header3 {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/wide-asphalt-road-with-buildings-horizon_1127-2192.jpg" width=100%></div>
<div id="header2"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/wide-asphalt-road-with-buildings-horizon_1127-2192.jpg" width=100%></div>
<div id="header3"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/wide-asphalt-road-with-buildings-horizon_1127-2192.jpg" width=100%></div>

<div style="margin-top:200px;padding:15px 15px 2500px;font-size:30px">
  <p><b>This example demonstrates how to shrink a header when the user starts to scroll the page.</b></p>
  <p>Scroll down this frame to see the effect!</p>
  <p>Scroll to the top to remove the effect.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor dummy text sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
    irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: You asked for how to **change the distance from the top at which the div gets smaller**. You can do this by adjusting the value of the top of the div. e.g. to start when the top of the div is half way up the screen:

```
// (position of the top of the div) - (half the screen height)
headerDiv.offsetTop - (window.innerHeight / 2);
```

```
function scrollFunction() {

  for (var i = 0; i < headerdivs.length; i++) {

    // adjust start point for changing the size, e.g.
    // (position of the top of the div) - (half the screen height)
    startChangingAt = (headerdivs[i].offsetTop) - (window.innerHeight / 2);
    if (startChangingAt < 0) startChangingAt = 0;

    if (document.body.scrollTop > startChangingAt || 
                  document.documentElement.scrollTop > startChangingAt ) 
      headerdivs[i].style.width = "80%";
    else 
      headerdivs[i].style.width = "100%";

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that appears right but I plan to have multiple overlapping elements of different sizes so I still do think I need a percentage so I can control each div independently.

Comment: @Aurochs I don't understand why you need percentages? You need to get the physical top position of the element to see if it is at the top of the screen. `scrollTop` tells you what that is on any screen size.

Comment: It doesn't matter what percentage of the screen has been scrolled. The device works with exact pixel values. `scrollTop` will always tell you the top of the element position on the screen even if the window size changes or if it moves because other elements change size. It is the definitive value you need.

Comment: Ok, I'm still trying to understand it. I will work with this, thank you!

Comment: Is there something else I need to do? I'm getting this error-

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null
    at scrollFunction (test.html:60) at window.onscroll

Comment: @Aurochs Its not finding one of the elements you are adding to your array. Make sure you have all your ids correct in the `getElementById` section.

Comment: It's working but I don't see any way to change the distance from the top at which the div gets smaller. The only number in the function is 0 and changing it seems to have no effect.

Comment: @Aurochs it gets smaller when the top of the div is at the top of the screen, the code dynamically gets this value. You can adjust this value to change the distance from the top. I have edited my answer with how to do this. If this helps maybe you can accept this answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the distance from the top of each section as well as their height. Then, you'll have to watch it that way.

```
let header = document.getElementById("header");
let boundingBox = header.getBoundingClientRect();
let distanceToTop = boundingBox.top;

if (document.body.scrollTop > distanceToTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop > distanceToTop) {
  document.getElementById("header").style.width = "80%";
} else {
  document.getElementById("header").style.width = "100%";
}
```

You can also play with the height of your section to add a percentage of visibility that will trigger the animation:

```
let header = document.getElementById("header");
let boundingBox = header.getBoundingClientRect();
let height = boundingBox.height;
let distanceToTop = boundingBox.top;

if (document.body.scrollTop > distanceToTop + height * 0.5|| document.documentElement.scrollTop > distanceToTop + height * 0.5) {
  document.getElementById("header").style.width = "80%";
} else {
  document.getElementById("header").style.width = "100%";
}
```

You Could also do it using the IntersectionObserver API, documentation here : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API